# How do I undo a 'git pull --allow-unrelated-histories' and get back to my original history?

Tags: node.js, git

I confused the remote url's for two different repos. The two repos correspond to a frontend and a backend application. I set the backend's remote-url to point to the frontend repo, and I didn't notice. I did a git pull, Git complained about unrelated histories so I kept pushing through and ran `git pull --allow-unrelated histories` fixed the "merge conflicts" and pushed the changes to the central repo. After viewing frontend code in the backend repo I slowly realized my blunder. So I tried to revert the changes but the backend repo has the frontend's git history baked into it so I keep seeing the frontend code files in the backend repo.
Here is what the backend's repo git history graph looks like at the moment:[image: I need to reset the repo to only include the right hand side of the history. The left hand side is the frontend's history line]

How do I undo this??? I need to keep the history from commit **e3282c79** down to **e6ddfacc**, and only this because it corresponds to the backend's git history. The left most line corresponds to the frontend's git history, and I don't need it.

I ran git revert to a commit previous the mixup but the git history still remained the same.

Comment: The fact that it was a `pull` rather than a `merge`, and that it involved the `--unrelated-histories` flag doesn't actually make a difference to what you need to do now, which is **not** a revert, it is to **re-point the branch**, discarding your merge commit and anything after it.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for this insight. Would you mind sharing how I can go about re-pointing the branch?

Comment: checkout the branch and do `git reset --hard $sha`, or do `git branch -f ${branch} ${new_tip_commit}` or use `git update-ref`.  Whichever you choose, make sure you understand what it does before you execute it.

Comment: @GeraCamoDev Look at the duplicate I pointed you to in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks! After doing a git reset --hard to the commit I wanted, I then did git push -f to fix the remote branch as well. Awesome! Thanks everyone!